# What is the difference between contiguous and continious memory

Tags: memory-management

Does anyone know if there some difference when I say in programming "contiguous" memory or "continuous" memory? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't heard anything like `continuous memory` but `Contiguous memory` memory means all the memory blocks for the running process is allocated one after another.  (OR) assigns process consecutive memory blocks (that is, memory blocks having consecutive addresses). Probably both are synonymous with the context.

You may look into [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_(operating_systems)#Single_contiguous_allocation) (OR) [Here](http://www.cs.iit.edu/~cs561/cs351/memory_management_FS_sched/index_mm_03.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, seems yes even if they looks synonymous it would be correct to use "Contiguous memory"

Answer (score 0):

The term **continuous memory** was coined by Hewlett-Packard (HP) to describe a unique feature of certain HP calculators whereby the calculator could internally sustain most, or in later models - all, of the contents of user memory (via battery-backed CMOS memory)... (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_memory)